# Class casting unclarity

Tags: java, oop, class, casting

I have the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractGroup {

private String name;
.
.
.
}
```

I have two empty classes that extend this abstract class:

```
public class GroupA extends AbstractGroup {
}

public class GroupB extends AbstractGroup {
}
```

Is there a way to cast the following without getting a `ClassCastException`:
(`group` is of type `GroupA`)

```
group = (GroupB)group;
```

I need this object instance to become `GroupB`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not possible. You cannot cast classes horizontally but only vertically. `GroupA` is not the subtype of `GroupB` so the exception always will be raised.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. You can cast up or down on Inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Actually you're wrong. You can cast only up on the hierarchy. Try this (casting down), see what happens: http://pastebin.com/iPrCZWGd .

Comment: casting down is possible if you have actually object of subclass and reference of superclass.

Comment: someMethod(SuperClass obj){
 
 if (obj instanceof SubClass){
  
  SubClass subref= (SubClass) obj;
 }
}......Isn't it valid  ..??

Comment: Yes, that works, but only because you're not actually casting `obj`. `obj` is already of type `SubClass`, you're just changing the reference to `SubClass`. If `obj` is actually of type `SuperClass`, then `instanceof` will return false.

Comment: well..I'll be pleased if you give me an example where actually type of an object is being changed.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot, because a GroupA is not an instance of GroupB.
How about:

```
public abstract class AbstractGroup {

  public Enum Group { GroupA, GroupB; }

  private String name;
  private Group membership;
.
.
.
}
```

And then:

```
group.setMembership(GroupB);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is not called *casting*, but *conversion*. Both terms are covered by the umbrella term *coercion*. Java will not convert an object for you automatically and it couldn't even if it tried since this is generally an ill-defined problem. You must write your own code that will do the conversion -- either in the form of a conversion constructor, or some static conversion method, or maybe an instance method in the source object that returns the converted object.

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't possible. But what you may like to do is add some constructor to the Groups to allow construction from a different implementation.

```
public class GroupA extends AbstractGroup {
    public GroupA(AbstractGroup otherGroup) {
        this.name = otherGroup.name;
    }
}
```

However if you find yourself needing to do this then perhaps your design may be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Possible if you do something like:

```
    GroupA groupAobj = new GroupA();
    AbstractGroup abstractObj = (AbstractGroup) groupAobj;
    GroupB groupBobj = (GroupB) abstractObj;
```

the code compiles and runs.

Comment: compiles, runs and throws an ClassCastException: `GroupA cannot be cast to GroupB` - the question is how to avoid this!

Comment: it throws an exception. Why don't you just catch the exception and work accordingly.

Comment: an Exception means it does not work. Why I don't catch it? because: 1st - it's not my problem, actually I don't see why that is needed; 2nd - the question (my understanding) is how to obtain an instance of GroupB from an instance of GroupA WITHOUT getting the Exception!

Comment: Then let's get to what actually is your need. Why do need to cast an object constructed by the classA constructor to refer to classB when the constructor of classB hasn't been run.

Comment: AGAIN: why **my** needs? I am **NOT** "hhh3112" the author of the question, I have **no** idea why **he** needs it - but I know that your code is not working, it does not solve the problem!